What's the relations between Quantum spin liquid and Quantum magnetism?
I am a fourth years undergraduate student. Recently, I am seeking that my research direction for my upcoming graduate program, and I found that my tutor is working that direction (as shown in the question).
And, I have one problem, What are the prospects of Quantum magnetism/spin liquid?
Thank you!

Depends on what you mean by the "prospects". "Prospects" could mean what technological advancements might it lead to, what problems would it solve, how will it deepen our understanding of nature.
Quantum spin liquids and condensed matter physics in general sits at the confluence of many interesting areas in physics: Magnetism, Quantum mechanics, Statistical mechanics, and Quantum field theory. Solid state systems and quantum spin liquids are a rich testing ground for theory and experiment, because we can synthesize hundreds of different materials with different electronic and magnetic interactions, all of which are ready to have theories made and experiments done to test the accuracy of those theories. There is a belief amongst many that understanding quantum spin liquids will help us understand high temperature superconductivity the same way understanding superfluids helped us understand low temperature superconductivity.
In summary- it's a very active research field that a young physicist can find plenty to sink their teeth into!

So that's how matter stand, Thank you!
